# Energy problem: What's wrong here?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, energy-conservation, friction

> A car ($m=540\,\text{kg}$) engine, has a power of $60\,\text{kW}$. The static friction coefficient between wheels and road is $k=0.6$. How long does it take to reach the speed of $27.7\,\text{m/s}$, with constant acceleration?

I have tried the following:

The energy to reach given speed is:
$$\frac{mv^2}{2}=\frac{540\cdot 27.7^2}{2}=2.07\cdot 10^5\,\text{J}$$

In the meanwhile I dissipated (because of friction):
$$-F_a\cdot s=-mgk\cdot\frac{1}{2}at^2=-mgk\cdot\frac{1}{2}\frac{\Delta v}{t}t^2=158,922\cdot t$$

The engine can do a work of $60,000\,\text{J}$ per second, so the work done is $60,000\cdot t$

So, I can do:
$$2.07\cdot 10^5\,\text{J}+158,922\cdot t=60,000\cdot t$$
And I obtain a negative time. How is possible? What's wrong?
Thanks a lot

Comment: You should check your working for the energy dissipated due to friction. I get $43,976.52W$.

Comment: @JasonDavies I have checked and checked again! Could you highlight my error? Thanks again

Comment: I just put the numbers in. Not sure what else I can say. Maybe you should show what numbers you used?

Comment: Working backwards, it looks like you forgot to put the number in for $\Delta{v}$.

Comment: @JasonDavies OMG, you're absolutely right. In my textbook there was $v_f=100 km/h$ originally, which I converted to $27,7 m/s$. When I was solving the problem, I forgot the conversion and I have used $\Delta v=100$. You saved my day. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Surferonthefall Darn it. I mentioned the lack of delta in my question too, earlier. So the initial velocity was not zero?

Comment: @namehere No, I used without distinction $v$ and $\Delta v$, because the first velocity was zero. The problem was a conversion error. Thank you too ;)

Comment: @Surferonthefall I had the delta on the t too...

Comment: @namehere same thing, in fact $t_0=0$, sorry for not enough clearness ;)

Comment: @Surferonthefall Finally got the answer straight. I got 13.7 meters per second, which I reckon is close enough to yours. Sorry for the confusion and slow answer; I was having dinner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you went wrong was $$-mgk \times \frac{1}{2}at^2=-mgk \times \frac{1}{2}\frac{\Delta v}{t}t^2$$. 
Instead it should be $$-mgk \times \frac{1}{2}\frac{\Delta v}{\Delta t}t^2$$
Anyways I would do it as $$F_{friction}s = mgk\frac{1}{2}at^2 = \frac{v-u}{2t}mgkt^2 = \frac{v-u}{2}mgkt = \frac{27.7ms^{-1}}{2} \times 540kg \times {10ms^{-2}} \times 0.6 \times t = (44874kgm^2s^{-3})t$$
So $$60kW \times t = (44874kgm^2s^{-3})t + 207000J$$ and solving gives $$t=13.7s$$

Comment: Wait... I seem to have got it wrong. Wait for me to rethink this thing...

Comment: No problem. The result reported on my textbook is 13s. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'll change it later to account for the fact that u is 100 meters per second

Comment: Darn, no matter which way I put it I couldn't get the answer. Sorry for that. I'm giving up.

Comment: @Surferonthefall Eureka! I'll edit my answer now!

Comment: @Surferonthefall No problem. I was actually ashamed it took me so long to do this... Argh my brains have rusted...

Answer (score 0):

If you have worked out it correctly then this simply means that you cant reach that speed with that powerful engine while the frictional coefficient is that much.What if you add some positive number to one side of your last equation so that time will now be positive?Then the left and right side of your equation will be same for some positive time but what does it mean of adding positive number to one side of equation?As you will add the number but it should have the same unit as of energy,then actually you are adding additional energy to the car engine.So without that much adding of additional energy you cant reach that velocity magnitude.